# Opposite of Buffer().toString()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have inherited a project and there is a .cert value which I am trying to reverse engineer to see how it was created. This value is created like so:

```
var rawCertValue = 'Q2VydGlmaWNhdGU6DQogICAgRG......'; // long value
var certificate = new Buffer(rawCertValue, 'base64').toString();
```

I have the original .pem key and can see that the certificate value in there matches the `certificate` variable that is generated above. What I am trying to figure out is how they got the `rawCertValue`

I guess my question is what would be the reverse function for:

```
new Buffer(rawCertValue, 'base64').toString();
```

Comment: You want to turn a base64 string into a buffer?

Comment: No, I want a function that would reverse the above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That [`new Buffer` variant is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding), you should use [`Buffer.from`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) instead which lets you specify the encoding. Also the [`toString` method](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) takes an optional encoding, which defaults to `utf8`. So your original code is equivalent to

```
var certificate = Buffer.from(rawCertValue, 'base64').toString('utf8');
```

The reverse operation for that would then be

```
var rawCertValue = Buffer.from(certificate, 'utf8').toString('base64');
```